# Is it possible to call a Compiz-Fusion plugin (ADD Helper) from an application?

Tags: linux, plugins, compiz

I'm in the process of planning an application that would make use of the "ADD Helper" plugin of Compiz-Fusion running on Linux.  Since I'm just in the planning stages, I basically want to know if it is feasible to use the plugin in a call from an application.

The application would theoretically display a dialog box, and black out the rest of the screen (what is achieved when invoking the ADD Helper plugin).

Is there a way to execute the ADD Helper plugin from within an application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the "ADD Helper" plugin, it appears it only darkens other windows, not the whole screen.

XScreenSaver darkens the entire screen before the screensaver starts. Why not look at its source to see how its done? I think the Gnome shutdown dialog darkened the whole screen, too, but it doesn't seem to do that anymore on Ubuntu Intrepid.

This is a little aside from the point, but why darken the screen anyway? As a user, I'd be very annoyed if your app darkened my screen. I may be monitoring other windows and I wouldn't be too please if your app prevented that.